# Loop only iterating once inside function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following function which should return **all** the tournaments and corresponding rounds **inside an array.**

When I call the function inside the body using a `print_r` I get **only one** tournament and round returned, however **there are multiple tournaments and rounds**. *It is like the loop exits after only one iteration*

```
function getTournaments(){
    global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT tournament, weekNum 
                FROM schedule
                GROUP BY tournament";
        $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute();
        $tournaments = $stmnt->fetchAll();

        $data = array();
        foreach($tournaments as $tournament){
                $data = array('tournament' => $tournament['tournament'], 'round' => $tournament['weekNum']);

        }//foreach
        return $data;
}//function

print_r(getTournaments());
```

**Database dump**

Here you can see the corresponding mysql statement run on the db

[image]

**My output / Problem**

As you can see on image below **I only get one tournament and round returned** when doing `print_r`, w*hy am I not getting all tournaments and rounds returned inside the function array? Am I missing something here?*

[image]

Comment: Instead of copying the array row by row just to rename a column, you could also use a column alias in your query `SELECT tournament, weekNum as \`round\`` and then `return $stmnt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel great advise thank you will definitely start implementing mentioned suggestion, learning each day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you over write `$data` in the loop you want to create new arrays (multidimensional):

```
$data[] = array('tournament' => $tournament['tournament'], 'round' => $tournament['weekNum']);
```

Comment: So you are saying I only missed the `[]` on `$data` array...? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should have used $data as an array :) 
Use this

```
 $data[] = array('tournament' => $tournament['tournament'], 'round' => $tournament['weekNum']);
```

instead of

```
$data = array('tournament' => $tournament['tournament'], 'round' => $tournament['weekNum']);
```